# Transfer learning/ retraining with TensorFlow Estimators

Tags: python, tensorflow, pre-trained-model

I have been unable to figure out how to use transfer learning/last layer retraining with the new TF [Estimator API](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/programmers_guide/estimators).

The `Estimator` requires a `model_fn` which contains the architecture of the network, and training and eval ops, as defined in the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/extend/estimators#constructing_the_model_fn). An example of a `model_fn` using a CNN architecture is [here](https://gist.github.com/AxOpus/4884ce80e679139036417a6dca723a61).

If I want to retrain the last layer of, for example, the inception architecture, I'm not sure whether I will need to specify the whole model in this `model_fn`, then load the pre-trained weights, or whether there is a way to use the saved graph as is done in the 'traditional' approach (example [here](https://github.com/samjabrahams/tensorflow-workshop/blob/master/.ipynb_checkpoints/AlexNet%20Transfer%20Learning-checkpoint.ipynb)).

This has been brought up as an [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/10155), but is still open and the answers are unclear to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to load the metagraph during model definition and use SessionRunHook to load the weights from a ckpt file.

```
def model(features, labels, mode, params):
    # Create the graph here

    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode, 
            predictions,
            loss,
            train_op,
            training_hooks=[RestoreHook()])
```

The SessionRunHook can be:

```
class RestoreHook(tf.train.SessionRunHook):

    def after_create_session(self, session, coord=None):
        if session.run(tf.train.get_or_create_global_step()) == 0:
            # load weights here
```

This way, the weights are loaded in first step and saved during training in model checkpoints.

Comment: I think that in this way you could restore the weights and and use them instead of random initialization, but what about freezing some layers so that they preserve their weights?